# const reference variable initialization

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, reference, initialization, constants

Consider

```
 int foo()
 { 
  return 1;
 }

 main()
 {
   const auto v1 = foo();
   const auto &v2 = foo();
 }
```

What are the differences between these two `const` variable initialization, in any aspect including the performance? Are there any situation where one preferred over other?

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Comment: @Slava this whole language is all about micro optimizations.

Comment: @grisevg I disagree. First of all it is absolutely unimportant how fast is incorrect program. So readability first, then micropotimizations and only where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

const auto v1 = foo()

This creates a const variable v1. As said creates means whatever foo() returns is now hold in v1.

const auto &v2 = foo()

is a reference to a const so foo() should return a reference. If whatever foo() returns doesn't support move semantics const auto &v2 would be faster.

P.S. In your case since foo() is returning an int it won't matter.

Comment: As I say in my answer, in this case `const auto &v2 = foo()` is very dangerous and should be avoided, unless you want to take advantage of extended lifetime of a temporary and have a good understanding of how it works.

Comment: The temporary variable to which the const refers won't be destroyed until v2 goes out of scope. Check this for more details https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/

Answer (score -1):

I'd be careful and would avoid const reference to a temporary (kudos to A.N. for the link [https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-c....](https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/)). It could be easily changed later to `auto &v2 = foo();` which is undefined behaviour.

Scott Meyers and Herb Sutter do recommend returning objects created on stack by value. You can utilise Named Return Value Optimization ([NRVO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364057(v=vs.80).aspx)) to ensure optimal performance, which in fact will be faster than returnig reference to a temporary or using move semantics.

I'm not saying to never extend temporaries lifetime by const references, I'm sure there could be use cases where it makes sense, for example when NRVO can't be done, all I'm saying is to avoid it unless there's a good reason. This is not very well known feature and it could lead to a dangerous code.

UPDATED: Corrected that `const auto &v2 = foo();` is actually valid code, but added explanation why it's still should be avoided. Also added link describing NRVO.

Comment: Then why  VS2012 does not even issue warning against it?

Comment: None of the compilers would complain because it's a const. Check this https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/